# Items not showing price in polyvore website

Tags: javascript, php

I am using polyvore clipper to clip items to polyvore. The clipper fetches all details such as url, image, title and price. upon saving, it is not showing price in the polyvore site.

Price and "buy at from " button also missing. any idea on how to achieve this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items that show up in the shop search ( where prices are shown) are the items that have the most engagement on Polyvore.

If you want your items to show up in the shop search you'll need to be more active with your items.

This way more people will see, save, and use your items. Hope that helps!